# .htaccess Redirect in case of 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, isapi-rewrite

I have this line of .htaccess
This line is used to get images from another server.

```
RewriteRule ^resources/fabricantes(.*)$ http://mysecondserver.com/arq/pictures/fab$1
```

than, if I have the url: http://myserver.com/resources/fabricantes/fab_1.jpg
this image will be get from: http://mysecondserver.com/arq/pictures/fab/fab_1.jpg

**The Problem:**
In some cases, the image doesn't exists on mysecondserver.com, how can I redirect to a "image unavailable" image in this cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think you need to understand that **this rule can only work from `mysecondserver.com` host not from `server.com`.**

On `mysecondserver.com` place this .htaccess in `/arq/pictures/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /arq/pictures/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ no-image.jpg [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

On mysecondserver.com, you would have .htaccess checking for -f status of the REQUEST_FILENAME. It could send the user back to the first server, if necessary. The alternative is to explicitly list all known failures back on your first server, which is a lot of work for you (even if you *have* a complete list). There's no way for the first server to know if a file actually exists on the second server.